# Call an external program from within OCaml

Tags: unix, ocaml, execv

I'm pretty new to OCaml and was trying to figure out how to call an external program from within OCaml.

I've been following the documentation [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html), and making the following call:

```
Unix.execv "cat text_file";;
```

This returns the following:

```
string array -> 'a = <fun>
```

How exactly do I access the returned anonymous function?

`cat text_file` is a simple attempt to print the contents of the file, the command I actually want to run is a bit more complex.  However, I presume that if I can get this running, I should be able to get my real program running.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first argument to `execv` is the program you want to run and the second is an array containing the arguments. Also, `execv` requires the full path to the program; you can use `execvp` to look up the program in the execution path. Furthermore the first argument to the program is the name of the program itself.
So you want `"/bin/cat"` as the first argument, not `"cat text_file"`, and `[| "cat"; "text_file" |]` as the second argument (or call `execvp` and pass `"cat"` as the first argument).

However, more often than not you actually want `system`, not `execv`.

Note that `system` allows you to pass a single string like you want and that `execv` (unlike `system`) never returns, i.e. once you call `execv` your program is done and the application you invoke takes over the process.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what sepp2k said, you might want to look into using `create_process` (for Unix.file_descr) or `open_process` (for channels).  These functions do a fork/exec and redirect the i/o for the process.  That way you can communicate with the process, which you can't do with `system`.

If you want to read the output of `cat` in your program, you can create a pipe using the `pipe` function, and then use the returned file_descrs for `create_process`.